# Power BI - combing columns in a clustered bar chart changes data values

Tags: charts, powerbi

I am combining data from multiple source tables into a single, consolidated table, with many calculated columns.

My main interest is to compare the counts for jobs that are late, deferred, and various other conditions, for many different work packs. The X axis has the name of work packs, and is filtered to "Top 15 by jobs late finished".

Individually, all of the counts of job status work properly, i.e. I can build separate bar charts for them.

When I bring 2 or more values into the chart to make a clustered bar chart, the counts are all change to wrong values. I am filtering each displayed value in a way that is appropriate for it (e.g. "LATE", "INCOMPLETE", "DEFERRED", and so on. These are all text values in calculated columns.

I must be missing something basic - why does bringing a second value into the chart have an effect on the previous value? And why are they both wrong after this?

I prepared images to demonstrate this but I don't have privileges to upload them. Briefly:

- Chart 1 shows count of Deferred jobs, with one work pack containing 660
- Chart 2 shows count of Late jobs, with the same work pack containing 279
- Chart 3 shows two bars per work pack, Late and Deferred. The particular work pack now has a count of 230 for both Late jobs and Deferred jobs (and all other work packs have both of their bars with the same count). This count is not correct for either Deferred jobs or Late jobs.

A job can't be in both Deferred and Late columns - they are exclusive.

Questions:
(1) Why does adding a second value affect an existing value in the chart?
(2) What traditional steps might be necessary to build a clustered bar chart from multiple calculated columns?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my method of calculating a text value ("LATE", "DEFERRED", etc) cannot be used. Attempting to display multiple COUNT values in a chart cluster gives incorrect counts.

The problem was resolved by changing the data type to "Whole Number" and calculating values of either 0 or 1. These values can be used for SUM in each measure, and give individual bars in the chart that do not affect each other.

The original approach seems valid to me and certainly works in Excel, but it just seems to be unacceptable in Power BI.